# No headers are being sent but PHP says that "Header may not contain more than a single header"

Tags: php, cookies

On a page with no output, I'm trying to set a cookie with:

```
//Setcookie
function mySet ($name, $value, $life = 86400)  {
    global $url;
    setcookie($name, $value, time()+$life, "/", $url, null, true);
}
```

The arguments I pass are `'user'` for the name and `'Sink'` for the value.

When using `var_dump(headers_list());`, it returns an empty array (`array(0) { }`)

I tried using `header_remove();` on the line before the setcookie just in case, but it still errors out with

> **Warning:** Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in **/var/www/dota/other/req.php** on line **117**

I have a file with a bunch of functions (just a ton of functions) that's called on every page - line 117 is the third line in the `mySet()` function (`setcookie()`

Additionally, the cookie is not set. However, refreshing the page both removes the error *and* sets the cookie, even though there's no code on the entire page that checks if the page has been refreshed. I can refresh the page as many times as I want and it works. The only code on the page is:

```
//Update last login, along with their steam name if they changed it
$query = "UPDATE users SET steamname = ?,loginip = ? WHERE steamid = ? ";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $steamprofile['personaname'], $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"], $steamprofile['steamid']);
$stmt->execute();

//Get the secret key
$query = "SELECT secretkey FROM users WHERE steamid = ? ";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
$stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $steamprofile['steamid']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt->get_result());

//Set the cookies
header_remove(); 
mySet('userKey', $result['secretkey']);
mySet('user', $steamprofile['personaname']);
var_dump(headers_list());
delCookie('type');
redir('/coach/browse.php');
```

Comment: and the line 117 is?

Comment: What's on line 117? And also, do you have any spaces before your `<?php` tag, or more than 2 new lines after your closing php tag (`?>`)?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I have a file with a bunch of functions (just a ton of functions) that's called on every page - it's the third line in the mySet() function (setcookie())

Comment: @Darren There are no spaces before `<?php` and no spaces after `?>`

Comment: edit with the print_r($url)

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer it outputs `learn2dota2.com`

Comment: if you comment this line *mySet('user', $steamprofile['personaname']);* what happens?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer The error still outputs, just one less time (it outputs twice in my code)

Answer (score 0):

A few things cold be causing this, but most likely it is the var_dump. Anything printing out to the browser will cause a header. If your redir() function also creates a header that would cause the error.

Is there any more to this file?

Also, if the file is pure PHP you should never include the closing PHP tag ?> this could also cause this error if there is an invisible control character in the file.

Comment: OP states that var_dump was added afterward for debugging the error, that it is still there when removed.

Comment: var_dump was added after the issue occurred to debug it. I removed it and it still breaks. redir() echos javascript but it shouldn't break anything as the cookies are set first, right? There is more to this file but it's all just a ton of functions that aren't called.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted. It could be with other code that has been left out here.

See here for relatively complete answer and things to look for or to try: [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Especially look at using headers_sent() as a debug tool to find out where your output is starting to get sent over unintentionally.